# Accessing the the sub object of a user made object from another class

Tags: java

I was wondering what the proper code to call a sub-object of an user made object declared that was in an arraylist in another class was.

I have an array list of of custom object A in class B and i need to call a specific sub object from the arraylist in class B in class C.

Comment: You may want to post some code to clarify your question. What is `sub-object` anyway?

Comment: The question is not very clear, what do you mean by "call a sub-object"? Calling a method from an object contained (by composition) in another object? Or by inheritance? You should post some code, it's going to be easier to understand. Maybe what's your looking for is java's reflection api : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html